# qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found."

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, qt5

I have installed [gqcnn](https://berkeleyautomation.github.io/gqcnn/install/install.html#run-pip-installation), [Pyrep](https://github.com/stepjam/PyRep) and [autolab_core](https://berkeleyautomation.github.io/autolab_core/install/install.html#option-1-pip). After that, I executed the code that my coworker wrote and, it ran fine on his computer.

However, I cannot run the code. The occurred error was

```
python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


In /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so:
  Plugin uses incompatible Qt library (5.15.0) [release]
"The plugin '/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so' uses incompatible Qt library. (5.15.0) [release]" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329991
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol _ZN11QFontEngine14bitmapForGlyphEj6QFixedRK10QTransform version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol _ZN11QFontEngine14bitmapForGlyphEj6QFixedRK10QTransform version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference)"
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/bak/anaconda3/envs/pyrep/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

If you want to see the full error in detail, please see [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ATmeucjVbamlPL1rYoi7ZLm84inzPTNhJM1ygawO-H0/edit?usp=sharing).
'/pyrep/' in above is my anaconda environment name.

It seems to be caused by qt. But I cannot fix this problem.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution!
https://github.com/stepjam/PyRep/issues/76

The problem was loading Qt in the conda environment.

When I typed `qmake -version`, the terminal window showed me the qt in anaconda.
After I followed the first answer at the above URL, I can fix the problem.

Answer (score 16):

This issue occurs when you use `opencv` with `pyqt5`. It looks like qt plugin internally used by `opencv` is not compatible with `pyqt5`. Just unset environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` after `import cv2` statement.

```
import os

os.environ.pop("QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH")
```

You could also update the platform plugin path after importing `opencv`

```
import os

os.environ.update({"QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH": "/home/udara/anaconda3/envs/research-headless/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/plugins/xcbglintegrations/libqxcb-glx-integration.so"})
```

Note that this will make `opencv` window functions unusable. If you want to use them, you have to build `opencv` from source without the `qt` plugin. You could build the `opencv` with `gtk` plugin instead of `qt`.

References https://forum.qt.io/post/654289

Comment: You just solved my day! Thank you <3

Answer (score 5):

Solved my issue through https://github.com/NVlabs/instant-ngp/discussions/300

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

> This seems to have been a problem with the cv2 Python package and how it loops in Qt

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add something here.

I had this issue, but on debian10, and none of the solutions mentioned helped. What did help, was to realize that, in my case, pip installed version 5.15.2 of pyqt5 by default. However, here (https://repology.org/project/python:pyqt5/versions) it is stated that the version of pyqt5 recommended for debian10 is 5.11.3.

When I reinstalled pyqt5 with that version:

> $ pip3 install PyQt5==5.11.3

the issue was fixed.
The point, is that it may be a good idea to check:

- Which version of pyqt5 is installed by pip by default
- Which version of pyqt5 is recommended for one's OS/distro

Comment: I have PyQt5==5.15.2 and reinstall it with 5.11.3 resolved my problem. Thanks

Comment: After spending hours on how to fix it, your solution is the good one. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This may be related to a [similar error message](https://askubuntu.com/q/308128).

I just came across this problem, in Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8, while trying to use [matplotlib_backend_qtquick](https://github.com/jmitrevs/matplotlib_backend_qtquick).

This answer in the mentioned thread solved it for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1069502

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on a machine that has no display/graphical output (e.g. a server), make sure that your script does not call any cv2 functions for graphical output like `cv2.namedWindow` or `cv2.imshow`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `conda list | grep 'qt'`
2. For each found entry do:

`conda remove --force package_name` where `package_name` is the name returned by previous command

Answer (score 0):

This is an `opencv` dependency issue with `pyQt5`. `pyQt5` doesn't support `opencv-contrib-python` fully. I was building an app with `mediapipe`, `opencv` and `pyQt5` modules and struggled with issues for days. I found that this dependency problem can't be solved fully by just uninstalling `opencv-contrib-python` and installing `opencv-python-headless`. This and all other solutions that I found regarding this issue are just a temporary fix and don't go well if you want to deploy the app or script on a new machine.

I found the best solution is to use pyQt6. pyQt6 supports opencv-contrib-python fully. So, just uninstall everything of `pyQt5` and install `pyQt6`.

This will uninstall every `pyQt5` modules:

```
pip freeze | grep -E '^PyQt5' | awk -F'==' '{print $1}' | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

then install `pyqt6`:

```
pip install pyqt6
```